# Discord.js how to make it so bot does not respind to dms

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How do I make it so people cannot use commands in dms, it crashes my bot.

Comment: Could you tell us what your current command code looks like?

Comment: Don't have a current code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent your bot from responding to DMs, your `message` event should contain a line of code that checks if the message in question originated from a guild. You can do this using the [`Message#guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) property, which is read-only and returns a potentially null value (as denoted by a "?" before its returned type in the docs).

```
//assuming the first parameter of your message event is named "message"
if (!message.guild) return; //so the callback does not continue to process the message further if it did not originate from a guild
```

Your bot likely crashes due to it expecting there to always be an associated [`Message#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), which is also a potentially null value. This will not be the case if the message did not originate from a guild, where the property will be `null`.

Without a code snippet &/or error message from you, I can't tell for certain, but if the lack of this specific property is not the cause, then your crash is probably caused by a similar issue where a null is returned when your code isn't written to handle such a value.